# How to write an at-least-N-terms query together with filter and must_not in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to match documents satisfying all the conditions below:

1. author == "tom"
2. status != "deleted"
3. **at least two**  of `f1-f4` fields match given values

(all fields are `keyword`)

```
{"size":24,
"query":{
  "bool":{
    "filter":[{"term":{"author":{"value":"tom","boost":1.0}}}],
    "must_not":[{"term":{"status":{"value":"deleted","boost":1.0}}}],
    "should":[
      {"term":{"f1":{"value":"v1","boost":1.0}}},
      {"term":{"f2":{"value":"v2","boost":1.0}}},
      {"term":{"f3":{"value":"v3","boost":1.0}}},
      {"term":{"f4":{"value":"v4","boost":1.0}}}
      ],
      "minimum_should_match":"2",
      "boost":1.0
  }}
}
```

**UPDATE & SUMMARY**

The query I post above is in fact correct, but my es provider installed a buggy custom plugin performing "query optimization" which leads to all "minimum_should_match" ignored. If you encounter the same problem and can't find any clue, maybe you should check if you have any suspicious plugin installed

Comment: everything in the update looks fine, i cant seem to replicate your test case, any chance you add `explain: true` to your query and see if theres anything suspicious  there? maybe the values are index'd improperly due to move from string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're query is correct, you just need to remove the `"adjust_pure_negative"` flag or change it to false.

In short elastic will "ignore" all your queries and just filters using the `must_not`'s in the case the flag is set to true. [source](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-does-adjust-pure-negative-flag-do/92348)

also you can remove the `boost:1` as the default value is 1 which makes it redundant.

EDIT: my test

```
    await client.index({index: 'test', id: 5, type: 'test', body: {author: "george", status: "deleted", f1: "v1", f2: "v2"}});
    await client.index({index: 'test', id: 6, type: 'test', body: {author: "george", status: "x", f1: "v1",}});
    await client.index({index: 'test', id: 7, type: 'test', body: {author: "george", status: "u", f1: "v1", f2: "v2"}});
    await client.index({index: 'test', id: 8, type: 'test', body: {author: "george", status: "q", f1: "v1", f4: "v4"}});
    await client.index({index: 'test', id: 9, type: 'test', body: {author: "george", status: "1", f3: "v3"}});
    let x = await client.search({
        index: 'test',
        body:
            {"size":24,
                "query":{
                    "bool":{
                        "filter":[{"term":{"author":{"value":"george","boost":1.0}}}],
                        "must_not":[{"term":{"status":{"value":"deleted","boost":1.0}}}],
                        "must":[{
                            "bool":{
                                "should":[
                                    {"term":{"f1":{"value":"v1","boost":1.0}}},
                                    {"term":{"f2":{"value":"v2","boost":1.0}}},
                                    {"term":{"f3":{"value":"v3","boost":1.0}}},
                                    {"term":{"f4":{"value":"v4","boost":1.0}}}],
                                "minimum_should_match":"2",
                                "adjust_pure_negative":false,
                                "boost":1.0}}
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative":false,
                        "boost":1.0}}},
    });
```

results:
2 hits as expected:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "7",
    "_score": 0.5753642,
    "_source": {
      "author": "george",
      "status": "u",
      "f1": "v1",
      "f2": "v2"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "8",
    "_score": 0.47000366,
    "_source": {
      "author": "george",
      "status": "q",
      "f1": "v1",
      "f4": "v4"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. `adjust_pure_negative` and `boost` are generated by the `SearchSourceBuilder` from the java rest high level client. I tried to set `adjust_pure_negative` to `false` manually, but the behavior of the two queries still remained the same.

Comment: i posted my testing code, take a look at it and tell me if you see any difference between my query and yours. in case you cant please post you mapping of the index (i'm assuming it wont be standard?) and also an example of a "false positive" document

Comment: I think it's exactly the same. Please check the update. It's really weird that `minimum_should_match` is not working at all, even in the most simple case

Comment: I have finally found the true cause. The ES provider from another team in my company installed a custom plugin performing 'query optimization', which lead to all 'minimum_should_match` clauses ignored. It's a severe bug.